# UILocalNotification missing NSLocalizedString value but is using it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uilocalnotification, nslocalizedstring

We use UILocalNotification in my project as reminders.

Our app is translated so we set the string value of the notification with NSLocalizedString.

Xcode 9 displays an error while setting the notification (e.g.) :

```
[strings] ERROR: C'est le moment de faire votre action not found in table Localizable of bundle CFBundle 0x102100370 </var/containers/Bundle/Application/7D6F3FEC-0526-4393-B592-20BFD44DA64B/Myapp.app>
```

This is not the key of the localized string nor the comment used on the NSLocalizedString and when the notification pops-up the proper value is displayed, but system will recognize it as a key and display it capitalized.

I've been stumbling on this for a while now, if someone could give me a hint on where to go that would be appreciated.

Comment: have you ever fixed the issue? I'm having the same problem with only one language out of 9

Comment: @Kappe honestly mate it's been so long i have no idea, i couldn't even reproduce it

Comment: I solved this, the issue was a not-unicode character in the .strings file that was breaking it, unfortunately XCode didn't dectect it and the failure was only at runtime.